# PHP file not running using XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I recently installed XAMPP v.3.2.2. I have since been trying to test if PHP is properly configured by Apache. But I keep getting this error every time I try to run any PHP file. I have stored the files under C: drive->XAMPP->htdocs.

 Can someone please tell me how to resolve this?
[image]

Comment: Are you suggesting that `test.html` does work if placed in the same directory and requested in the same way? The output you are seeing is a "404 Not Found" response, as if the file does not exist at all, not that "PHP is not running"?

Answer (score 1):

"404 Not Found" response means file doest not exist in that directory. i would suggest to recheck the name of the file you are calling. there might be some file naming issue